# Spring MVC - Display datas from DB in browser

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jsp, spring-mvc

As in title, i wanna display datas from DB with Spring MVC help in browser.

i create Dynamic Web Project in Spring, write a few lines of code, and it doesn't work :x

As i run this on local srv Tomcat v8.5, it's show me only a columns that i made - no datas :/

Could some1 look at my code? Did you see anythink wrong?

BTW. It's written in .jsp file in Spring.

Thanks for help!

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>

<%
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
%>
<h2 align="center">
    <font><strong>Retrieve data from database in jsp</strong></font>
</h2>
<table align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="1">
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#A52A2A">
        <td><b>id</b></td>
        <td><b>user_id</b></td>
        <td><b>Password</b></td>
        <td><b>Name</b></td>
        <td><b>Email</b></td>
    </tr>
    <%
        try {
              connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/serie_db","postgres","admin");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM serie";

        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
%>
<tr bgcolor="#DEB887">

    <td><%=resultSet.getString("id")%></td>
    <td><%=resultSet.getString("name")%></td>
    <td><%=resultSet.getString("datefrom")%></td>
    <td><%=resultSet.getString("dateto")%></td>
    <td><%=resultSet.getString("feed")%></td>
</tr>
<%
    }
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
</table>
```

Edit: That's my error log
Tricks like:
project/properties/projectFacets/runtime/ - done...
import into lib postgresql-42.0.0.jar - done

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:123)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:60)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:131)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for     jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/serie_db
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:156)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: please post your error message, Java class and web.xml with applicationContext

Comment: I just add the error message, what do you think about that?

Comment: It seems you did not add lib into your project correctly

Answer (score 0):

Seems your problem is you are not adding the postgresSQL driver to the project classpath. Then Tomcat cant find the driver to access to your DB.

But more important that this mistake is the fact you are not respecting the MVC (Model-View-Controller) pattern, you should NEVER access from the view to the DB directly, you need to access to the controller and the controller will delegate to the proper service to do that task.

I think would be good if you start from scratch from this example [Web app example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

Its simple and you will have it working quite fast.

Comment: Yeah, that's true - i need to start from beginning with that. But i will be grateful for help with that error... i add a postgresql driver to the classpath as a .jar file.. nothing changed :/ what do you think?

Comment: For your exception seems you are not placing the driver jar in the right place, or your application is not able to find it in some way